# Preventing windows resizing from enlarging PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

I have a simple splash screen Windows Form in my application which, in the Visual Studio designer, looks like [THIS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBhfu.png)

The logo and the progress ring are each inside a PictureBox.

However, when I try to render the application on a windows 10 PC with the text and app scaling set to higher than 100% (for example, a 1080p 15.6-inch laptop), the result kind of looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeqpH.png) (Taken from a PC with 125% resizing).

Do you know of a way to prevent the PictureBoxes from scaling, or perhaps a way to make the form scale up to keep track with the PictureBoxes?

EDIT: Just to be clear, it's the images INSIDE the PictureBoxes that scale up, not the PictureBoxes themselves.

Comment: Have you tried   myPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom ?? this will scale the picture box accordingly.

Comment: The images are just fine, it is the rest of the form that is not scaling correctly.  When the user asks for display items to be 125% bigger then the form of course needs to be 125% bigger as well.   It is not.  How you got that wrong is never visible from a screenshot, it requires repro code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting myPictureBox.SizeMode to PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom solved the issue (Thanks Adds.)